# Orbeon Runner - Calculated value

Tags: orbeon

I made a form with some text output controls that have calculated values by some others controls that have calculated value too. The problem is that, in test mode (from builder), these controls are working as should. In runner, these controls are always 0 (empty). After saving the document and opening it again, the values are correct, but not refreshing.

Here is my instance:

```
<xforms:instance id="fr-form-instance">
    <form>
        <section-1>
            <first>
                <first_amount/>
                <first_percent/>
                <first_total/>
            </first>
            <second>
                <second_amount/>
                <second_percent/>
                <second_total/>
            </second>
            <third>
                <third_amount/>
                <third_percent/>
                <third_total/>
            </third>
            <total/>
            <average/>
        </section-1>
    </form>
</xforms:instance>
```

And my bindings:

```
<xforms:bind xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel" id="fr-form-binds"
             nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')">
    <xforms:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
        <xf:bind name="first" id="first-bind" ref="first">
            <xf:bind name="first_amount" id="first_amount-bind" ref="first_amount"
                     type="xf:decimal"/>
            <xf:bind xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" name="first_percent"
                     id="first_percent-bind"
                     ref="first_percent"
                     type="xf:decimal"
                     constraint="./text()&gt;=0 or string-length(./text())=0"/>
            <xf:bind xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" name="first_total"
                     id="first_total-bind"
                     ref="first_total"
                     calculate="(../first_amount/text() * ../first_percent/text()) div 100"
                     type="xf:decimal"/>
        </xf:bind>
        <xf:bind name="second" id="second-bind" ref="second">
            <xf:bind name="second_amount" id="second_amount-bind" ref="second_amount"
                     type="xf:decimal"/>
            <xf:bind xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" name="second_percent"
                     id="second_percent-bind"
                     ref="second_percent"
                     type="xf:decimal"
                     constraint="./text()&gt;=0 or string-length(./text())=0"/>
            <xf:bind xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" name="second_total"
                     id="second_total-bind"
                     ref="second_total"
                     calculate="(../second_amount/text() * ../second_percent/text()) div 100"
                     type="xf:decimal"/>
        </xf:bind>
        <xf:bind name="third" id="third-bind" ref="third">
            <xf:bind name="third_amount" id="third_amount-bind" ref="third_amount"
                     type="xf:decimal"/>
            <xf:bind xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" name="third_percent"
                     id="third_percent-bind"
                     ref="third_percent"
                     type="xf:decimal"
                     constraint="./text()&gt;=0 or string-length(./text())=0"/>
            <xf:bind xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" name="third_total"
                     id="third_total-bind"
                     ref="third_total"
                     calculate="(../third_amount/text() * ../third_percent/text()) div 100"
                     type="xf:decimal"/>
        </xf:bind>
        <xf:bind xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" name="total"
                 id="total-bind"
                 ref="total"
                 calculate="sum(instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/first/first_total/text()) + sum(instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/second/second_total/text()) + sum(instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/third/third_total/text())"
                 type="xf:decimal"/>
        <xf:bind xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" name="average"
                 id="average-bind"
                 ref="average"
                 type="xf:decimal"
                 calculate="instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/total/text() div (count(instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/first) + count(instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/second) + count(instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/third))"/>
    </xforms:bind>
</xforms:bind>
```

Comment: Can you provide an entire working form? Feel free to send it to me directly at ebruchez at orbeon.com. Also, what version of Orbeon Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me with the form provided, both in test mode and when deploying the form (see the screenshot). I am using Orbeon Forms 4.1.

Not that it should matter, but here are a couple of comments on your XPath expressions:

- `text()` is almost never needed in XPath, and you can remove all such occurrences of `/text()` in your expressions
- instead of `&gt;=`, you can use the `ge` operator, which is more readable

[image: screenshot].

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this happens only in my application proxy.